# IBM DB2 Scalar Function Parameters in Prepared Statement

Tags: java, db2

I have a db2 table t1 where one of the columns is populated by utilizing a scalar function that takes two string params.

```
function(string foo, string bar)
```

In prepare the sql code as follows:

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = function(?, 'foobar') WHERE t1.id = ?
```

When i now add a parameter to the prepared statement i get an error that the first parameter is of the wrong type.

```
for (Entry entry : entries) {
    preparedStatement.setString(1, entry.getDesc());
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, entry.getId());
}
```

I already tried wrapping the first param in single quotes but that didn't work. Did anyone else have this problem and has come to a solution?
The main problem is that i'm now sure how the db2 engine prepares the first string parameter for the scalar function so that the error is thrown in the first place.

Comment: The [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) interface has `set<Datatype>` functions with 2 or 3 parameters, and the 1-st one is `int` - parameterIndex. Why do you try to use `set<Datatype>` functions with only a single parameter?

Comment: Sry, that was a typo.

Comment: Try `function(cast(? as varchar(xxx)), 'foobar')`, where `xxx` the corresponding length of the 1-st string parameter of the function, and provide the exact error code and message you get from Db2. The function's 1-st parameter must be of `varchar` data type in this case. If its 1-st parameter is of another data type, then use the corresponding `cast` and `set<Datatype>`.

Comment: The cast already did it. Thanks. Do you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `function(cast(? as varchar(xxx)), 'foobar')`, where `xxx` the corresponding length of the 1-st string parameter of the function. The function's 1-st parameter must be of `varchar` data type in this case. If its 1-st parameter is of another data type, then use the corresponding cast and `set<Datatype>`.
You need to do it, since there may be multiple functions with the same name and number of parameters, but with different data types. And Db2 must know which function to use exactly during the query compilation (prepare).